# Is it possible to filter certain controller calls from the production log files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Due to the way our TechOps people have things set up, our load balancer hits our start page very frequently. This in itself isn't really a problem but it fills up our production logs with the same calls over and over.
I know there's a way in Rails to filter out certain parameters from showing in the logs but is it possible to turn off certain routes from being logged?